# rospy threading model

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it correct to assume that a new thread will be used for every instance of every subscription and service callback?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9543/rospy-threading-model/) by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1479 on 2011-03-23

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a particular topic, there is only one thread that all the subscribers share.

Each service callback does get its own thread because there can only be one service callback for a particular service.

Future versions of rospy will likely have a different, more versatile threading model for subscriptions.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-26**:
What @kwc is describing is the callbacks.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-03-24**:
Yes, there is only one thread for a subscription, which includes the work of doing all the callbacks.

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-03-24**:
Thanks. What about the callbacks? I had the impression that those were executed serially from a single queue for all subscribers.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-03-24**:
For each subscribed topic in a node, there is a thread.  5 subscribed topics, 5 threads.  If you have two subscriptions to one topic, one thread.   Publishers are synchronous/blocking, so the publishing occurs in the same thread.  (the i/o engine of rospy is overdue for a rewrite)

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-03-24**:
Ken, did you mean 'for a particular node ( or maybe nodehandle?), there is only one thread...'? If I have a python node that subscribes to 5 topics how many threads are in play? What about on the publishing node's side?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-03-24**:
Each service has a single, dedicated thread that handles the underlying transport and calling into the callback.  Service requests are processed serially in the order they come off the socket.

**Comment by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on 2011-03-24**:
OK.  For services, does it use a threadpool or spin up a new thread on each request?

**Comment by [Seanny123](https://answers.ros.org/users/8436/seanny123/) on 2013-12-09**:
The detailed replies have been great, but just to eliminate all ambiguity, from what I understand this also means that my script will wait for my callback to end before starting another callback, even if a subscription releases a new message. Is this correct?

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2016-09-15**:
Just to clarify, after finding something suprising - while one thread will serially run all subscription callbacks, services get a separate thread for each connection (https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/kinetic-devel/clients/rospy/src/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py#L247), thus one per client.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The accepted answer is not correct, at least with Kinetic. Consider the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import threading

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Empty

global i
i = 0


def callback(_):
    global i
    i += 1
    j = i
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        print('sleeping: %d, thread: %s' % (j, threading.current_thread()))
        rospy.Rate(1).sleep()
    print('exiting loop for %d: %s' % (j, rospy.is_shutdown()))


def main():
    rospy.init_node('foooo')
    sub = rospy.Subscriber('foo', Empty, callback, queue_size=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    rospy.spin()
```

Then, call rostopic twice by running the following command twice in parallel in different shell sessions:

```
rostopic pub /foo std_msgs/Empty "{}"
```

Observe the following output:

```
sleeping: 1, thread: <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140177158719232)>
sleeping: 2, thread: <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140177150326528)>
sleeping: 1, thread: <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140177158719232)>
sleeping: 2, thread: <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140177150326528)>
sleeping: 1, thread: <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140177158719232)>
sleeping: 2, thread: <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140177150326528)>
sleeping: 1, thread: <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140177158719232)>
sleeping: 2, thread: <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140177150326528)>
sleeping: 1, thread: <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140177158719232)>
sleeping: 2, thread: <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140177150326528)>
sleeping: 1, thread: <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140177158719232)>
sleeping: 2, thread: <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140177150326528)>
```

---

Originally posted by [rsinnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/33426/rsinnet/) with karma: 101 on 2018-01-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) on 2018-07-13**:
You are right.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2023-02-05**:
I don't quite understand why the observed output demonstrates that the accepted answer is incorrect. Of course time may have passed and those two comments are out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It actually seems like a subscriber process has one thread per topic subscribed *per publisher*. So if node A subscribes to topic `/foo` and node B publishes to topic `/foo` and node C also publishes to topic `/foo`, node A will have 2 callback threads.

ros_thread_sub.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import threading

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def callback(msg):
    print("Msg from %s on thread %s" % (msg.data, threading.current_thread()))

def main():
    rospy.init_node('foooo')
    rospy.Subscriber('foo', String, callback, queue_size=1)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

ros_thread_pub.py (starting publisher B and C in separate terminals)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import threading
import sys

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

global proc_id
proc_id = ""

def publisher():
    msg = String(proc_id)
    r = rospy.Rate(1)
    pub = rospy.Publisher('foo', String, queue_size=1)
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        print("publishing")
        pub.publish(msg)
        r.sleep()

def main():
    global proc_id
    proc_id = sys.argv[1]
    rospy.init_node(proc_id)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=publisher)
    thread.start()
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Console output:

```
Msg from B on thread <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140237958694656)>
Msg from B on thread <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140237958694656)>
Msg from B on thread <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140237958694656)>
Msg from B on thread <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140237958694656)>
Msg from C on thread <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140237950301952)>
Msg from B on thread <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140237958694656)>
Msg from C on thread <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140237950301952)>
Msg from B on thread <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140237958694656)>
Msg from C on thread <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140237950301952)>
Msg from B on thread <Thread(/foo, started daemon 140237958694656)>
```

---

Originally posted by [zacwitte](https://answers.ros.org/users/26086/zacwitte/) with karma: 170 on 2018-04-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8